# TSQL How to exec a stored procedure inside select query?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

is it possible to execute a storep procedure inside select query ?

```
select e.Name, dbo.get_sth e.Id
from emp e
```

I get the error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'e.Id'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But you can execute a function inside a select statement. So recreate your Stored Procedure as a function and this should work.

It will be called for every row so be careful of performance if returning many rows.

Comment: This is the exact answer I'm looking for as I need to pass a bunch of records to a stored procedure. Sounds like Tony might want to create a view instead of a function. Hard to say without knowing what the USP does.